# Haskell, taking a list of pairs (value,index) and making it a single list [Int]

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, computer-science

I am fairly new at Haskell and have been trying to solve this.
I have been trying to take a list of pairs and condense it down to a single list

For example if I had the pairs:

```
[(2,0),(4,5),(3,10)]
```

The list should return

```
[2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,3]
```

The idea is that the first element of the pair is the value and the second value is the index.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
finalList :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
finalList ((x,y): xs) = replicate y 0 ++ [x] ++ finalList xs
finalList _ = []
```

However with this issue I am not getting the desired padding of 0s that I would like to have . I am instead getting something like:
`[6,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a hint. I will also assume that the indices in the input list are in increasing order.

A possible approach is to first define an auxiliary function that takes one more argument, an "index" counting how many elements we have produces so far. Here is a sketch of a part of the code you might use.

```
f :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int -> [Int]
f []                _ = ...  -- base case
f ((value, pos):xs) ix
  | ix == pos = value : ...  -- here we recurse
  | otherwise = 0     : ...  -- here we recurse too
```

Roughly put, the logic above is: keep track of the current position `ix`: if the position is the wanted one `pos`, emit `value`. Otherwise emit `0` as a filler.

In both cases we recurse, and we need to increment the current position `ix`. The current position `is` will be initially set to zero as follows:

```
finalList :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
finalList xs = f xs 0
```

Note that when we recurse, we also need to understand what to do with the input list. I will leave that to you.

Comment: So far I've added 
`
f ((value, pos):xs) ix
  | ix == pos = value : f (xs) (ix + 1)  
  | otherwise = 0     : f ([(value,pos)]) (ix + 1)   
`
and it looks like if I try any other implementation I get an infinite loop any tips? @chi

Comment: @Wayplace That looks almost OK. In the second case, you should keep the input list as it is, e.g. `f ((value,pos):xs) (ix+1)`. The fact that you get an infinite recursion is weird, though: my code assumes that the positions `pos` in the list are increasing -- are they? If they are not as in `[(11,5),(12,3),..]` then you will indeed get stuck into an infinite sequence of zeros.